# How to track visitors of blog posts with Google Analytics Plugin in GatsbyJS?

Tags: api, google-analytics, gatsby

The question is simple, I've added google analytics to my GatsbyJS website, but I don't know how to track visitors to single posts through it. Of course I know to look at GA page, but I want to find a way to use that info on my website. Can someone help me?
This is the google analytics plugin setup [I intentionally did not put GA Tracking ID here]:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
    options: {
      trackingId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID",
      head: true,
      anonymize: true,
      respectDNT: true,
    },
  },
```

Let's say I have a single post/page that I want to know how many visitors it has through GA and post the MORE IMPORTANTLY, to post that number on that page, what sort of API should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find number of pageview in `Behaviour` report: in `All pages` report filter with the page page you want.

You can get that information via API using **Google Analytics Reporting API**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics